Universal links app-site-association file were not downloading in iOS
I'm currently working on universal links.
iOS application is build with react-native framework
Steps I did to achieve the universal links
Step 1 :
Created an app-site-association file
My AASA file format :
 "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "TEAMID.BUNDLEID"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "*",
            "?": {
              "$web_only": "true"
            },
            "exclude": true
          },
          {
            "/": "*",
            "?": {
              "%24web_only": "true"
            },
            "exclude": true
          },
          {
            "/": "/e/*",
            "exclude": true
          },
          {
            "/": "*",
          },
          {
            "/": "/",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Step 2 :
I have hosted the app-site-association file in .well-known path
https://staging.***.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
Step 3 :
I have enabled associated domains and added applinks in Entitlements also
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:staging.***.com</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.multicast</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Step 4 :
https://app-site-association.cdn-apple.com/a/v1/staging.***.com
With the above apple cdn url , I can able to see the app-site-association file which I hosted in https://staging.***.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association path.
Step 5 :
I have checked the console of phone with Xcode -> Devices -> Console
When my application trying to down the AASA file from my server , I got this below error :
swcd : Error getting enterprise-managed associated domains data. If this device is not enterprise-managed, this is normal: Error Domain=SWCErrorDomain Code=1701 "Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to get associated domain data from ManagedConfiguration framework., Line=298, Function=<private>}
swcd : Developer mode enabled: NO
Kindly help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in advance.

The message from the console that you have shown is nothing to do with universal links.  It even explicitly says that it isn't an error. Have you tried the universal links debugging feature under the device developer settings? Have you tried creating a sysdiagnose in order to get the universal links data?

Thanks.Actually deep linking is working when I click the link from notes , I have tried with slack by mistake.
